# ASP.NET MVC5 Get all registered AspNetUsers in a list view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My goal is simple. I want to list all registered users in my ASP.NET MVC5 for administrational purposes. Here's my AccountController code:

```
     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
     public ActionResult AdminUserManagement()
     {
        var context = new IdentityDbContext();

        var allUsers = context.Users.ToList();



        var viewModels = new List<ManagerUserViewModel>();

        foreach (var user in allUsers)
        {
            viewModels.Add(new ManagerUserViewModel { UserID = user.Id, UserName =  user.UserName, Role = user.Roles.First().Role.ToString() });
        }

        return View(viewModels);
    }
```

But fore some reason the allUsers list, is empty. 
When I run the application, The View works just fine, but picks up no Users at all.

The View:

```
@model IEnumerable<GUI.Models.ManagerUserViewModel>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "User Management";
 }

 <h2>User Management</h2>


 <table class="table">
    <tr>
       <th>
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
       </th>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
       </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
 </tr>
  }

 </table>
```

The IdentityDB:

```
using ClassLibrary.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


namespace DAL.DataContexts
{
   public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityDb()
        : base("WhitelabelDb")
    {
    }
}
}
```

What's wrong with my code, and why?

Comment: Put a breakpoint over `var allUsers ...` . Does that get populated?

Comment: No it doesn't. I alredy put the breakpoint over that line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looking at your code I can't see a bigger problem, but you aren't disposing your database context as you should.
Try the following code and see if it helps:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminUserManagement()
{
    IEnumerable<ManagerUserViewModel>() viewModels;
    using(var context = new IdentityDbContext()){

        viewModels =
            context.Users
            .Include("Roles")
            .Select(u =>
                new ManagerUserViewModel { 
                    UserID = u.Id, 
                    UserName =  u.UserName, 
                    Role = u.Roles.First().Role.ToString() 
                }
            ).ToList();
    }

    return View(viewModels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of tolist , please try below , i am not sure, it works or not

```
 viewModels.Tolist();
```

**or**

send your allUsers to your view directly using without **foreach**.

Write your foreach code in your **view**

Comment: I think that foreach-ing the IQueryable would result in a N+1 query, i.e. `foreach(var user in allUsers)`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using IdentityDb instead of IdentityDbContext:

```
var context = new IdentityDb();
```

the rest should be the same.